# 'Open in a new page'. Should a text link or a button be used to show this behaviour?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks

I'm designing an interface which includes 8 pieces of content underneath the content is an option for the user to 'see more'.

This 'see more' component is a requirement for mobile and desktop. Slightly more users are currently viewing the website on mobile.

In regards to the design of the 'see more', is it better to use a text link or a button? (I've also been told it's a business requirement to use one design pattern for both mobile and desktop)

Comment: If possible, could you show a screenshot of how it is now? or even a diagram would do fine.

Comment: Both options are acceptable, but buttons will be more inviting and noticeable. If you want to encourage users to click, you should definitely use a button.

Comment: Without prior warning, if a text-link opened in a new page I'd be somewhat surprised (and possibly a little irritated). If a button did that, I'd be less surprised (and probably not annoyed). If you indicate beforehand that a new page will open, then either can be used (though I'd probably prefer a button).

Answer (score 3):

Keeping [Affordance](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/affordances-and-design) in mind, please choose a button as most of your users are using Mobiles -

---

[image]